# How to regexp a comma separated list of predefined words?

Tags: regex

EDIT:

for now, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23621738/551357

As a compendium, here's an extract of some raw code I used for a first attempt to programmatically build the regexp, and it works:

```
$product_category_slugs_str = 'cat1|cat2|cat3|cat4'; //fake product category names
$product_category_slugs_count = count(explode('|',$product_category_slugs_str));
$rule = "($product_category_slugs_str)";

$current_lookahead = '';
$increment = 2;

for($i=0; $i<$product_category_slugs_count; $i++){
  //will produce consecutive negative lookaheads like (?!\1)(?!\3)(?!\5)
  $current_lookahead .= '(?!\\' . (1+$i*$increment) . ')';
  //zero or one word checked by negative lookahead and preceded by a comma
  $rule .= "(,$current_lookahead($product_category_slugs_str))?";
}

$rule .= '\/?$';//since it's for a url, adds an ending slash
```

---

I've got to match a string containing an arbitrary number of comma separeted words picked from a predefined list. So, if the list is:

- word1
- word2
- word3

the regexp should match strings like:

- 'word1'
- 'word1,word3'
- 'word3'
- 'word3,word1,word2'

etc, but not 'word3,word1,a_word_not_in_whitelist'

I really can't figure out how..
By the way, the whitelist of words is an array, so I could build the regexp programmatically, if needed, eventually.

Could be something like

(word1|word2|word3) followed by zero or more ",(word1|word2|word3)"

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote in the question works like this

```
(word1|word2|word3)(,(word1|word2|word3))*
```

Comment: Yeah I was just trying out, it works.. The only possible issue with this rule is that it would let things like word1,word1. Not a real problem in my specific use case, but sure, it would be better if I could avoid. How could I do?

Comment: I've found out here a pattern using negative look-ahead, not very elegant though, but maybe the only possible one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621719/regex-to-validate-a-comma-separated-list-of-options

Comment: If that is not an example, and is real words, then `(word[123])`

Comment: @Stratboy, that works for literals, but regex isn't built for that kind of logic. As far as I know you can't use that with back references.

Comment: Maybe just add another non-regex check for `count(word) <= 1`